# What is Article 288 in the context of Brexit?

Tags: european-union, brexit

British parliamentarian [Sir Bill Cash MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Cash) [writes](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2020/02/01/let-crystal-clear-unlike-previous-administration-boris-johnsons/):

> We now move on to the next stage of negotiations. Let it be crystal
>   clear that, unlike under the previous administration, Boris Johnson’s
>   government will not capitulate nor is legally bound to capitulate to
>   the terms and conditions set by the European Union as Article 288 of
>   the treaty clearly shows. And we cannot allow the EU to insist that we
>   are unable to benefit from, or be competitive outside the European
>   Union. We must be allowed to diverge as necessary. This is Boris
>   Johnson’s Churchill moment.

What Article 288 is he referring to?

Comment: Who is Cash? Is that a notable person in British politics?

Comment: @Trilarion Sir Bill Cash is a well-known Eurosceptic. He is more known for serving on committees than holding government office. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Cash

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote?

Comment: @Ben - Probably because a simple google search would have uncovered the answer for you in seconds

Comment: I did google it, and found Article 288 TFEU, but I couldn't connect the contents of the Article to the point Bill Cash was trying to make, so I wanted to check.

Comment: @Valorum the point of posting questions on SE, whatever the topic, is to hopefully gain advantage of specialized knowledge or insight.

Comment: @JohnK - And if was the downvoter, that would be an excellent observation. Since I'm not, it's pretty redundant

Comment: @Valorum I didn't think you were the downvoter,  just defending ppl that ask what can seem pretty easy to answer questions.  Anyway, I probably inferred too much from your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CONSOLIDATED VERSION OF THE TREATY ON THE FUNCTIONING OF THE EUROPEAN UNION
>
> PART SIX
> INSTITUTIONAL AND FINANCIAL PROVISIONS
>
> TITLE I
> INSTITUTIONAL PROVISIONS
>
> CHAPTER 2
> LEGAL ACTS OF THE UNION, ADOPTION PROCEDURES AND OTHER PROVISIONS
>
> SECTION 1
> THE LEGAL ACTS OF THE UNION
>
> Article 288
>
> (ex Article 249 TEC)
>
> To exercise the Union's competences, the institutions shall adopt regulations, directives, decisions, recommendations and opinions.
>
> A regulation shall have general application. It shall be binding in its entirety and directly applicable in all Member States.
>
> A directive shall be binding, as to the result to be achieved, upon each Member State to which it is addressed, but shall leave to the national authorities the choice of form and methods.
>
> A decision shall be binding in its entirety. A decision which specifies those to whom it is addressed shall be binding only on them.
>
> Recommendations and opinions shall have no binding force.

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A12012E288

This is the only Article 288 in EU treaty law, so it must be the one which is being referred to...

Comment: This is the whole standards and deviations thing that Javid and Patel have been contradicting each other on this week?

Comment: @Jontia I think so - not being a member state, the EU can no longer require the UK to follow its standards simply by publishing a regulation or directive, unless the UK agrees to that binding in any treaty.  Any standards to be followed will need to be agreed separately between the UK and the EU.

Comment: What does Bill Cash mean by referring to this article? EU laws continue to apply per the WA.

Comment: @Ben I assume he means that to prove its commitment to Brexit the UK government must burn its trading relationship with Europe by insisting on diverging from EU standards even where there is no business benefit once the transition period of the WA is complete.

Comment: @Ben he's referring to the final result after the transition period; that being freed from the EU regulatory apparatus is non-negotiable during the transition negotiations.